# Different nslookup answers on different clients in local network with local DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, ping, nslookup

Situation:
I have a few clients in a local network.
I have a server named amp003 with IP address 192.168.4.13
I have two DNS servers (each one on relative DC server).

On client 1 I did following:

```
nslookup amp003 DNS1
-DNS1's IP
-192.168.4.13
nslookup amp003 DNS2
-DNS2's IP
-192.168.4.13
```

On client 2 I did following:

```
nslookup amp003 DNS1
-DNS1's IP
-node not found
nslookup amp003 DNS2
-DNS2's IP
-node not found
```

On client 2 ping amp003 returns also node not found.

I did `ipconfig /flushdns` on client2 successfully, but it didn't help me. Rebooted client2 as well.
In network IPv4 settings there are DNS1 and DNS2 listed, so no other DNS is providing data.

Any clues?

Comment: Does it work if you use the FQDN on client 2? E.g. `ping amp003.<your-domain-here>`. You should see the FQDN where you do a reverse lookup `nslookup 192.168.4.13 DNS1`.

Comment: There could always be an AV client (AVG for example does such strange stuff) and/or a IPv6 DNS (maybe set manually on the client).